# What's the difference between With and View in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

programmers.
I have a question.
I know that Oracle's WITH is used when using subquery a lot, what is the difference from View?

Comment: A CTE (a defined by `WITH`) is limited to a single query.  A view can be used by multiple queries and the definition lives in the database.

Comment: Some views may act as tables as well; they can even be updatable. The main drawback I can see for views is that developers tend to forget to version view's source code in the repository. The same can be said about stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

With: The WITH clause is a kind of inline view or a temporary table. The advantage of using  is that if there is multiple reference to a subquery it can be replaced temporary table, rather being written multiple times.

View: It is a virtual table based on the result of an SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

A View is a type of persistent sql object like a table or index used to produce a query result while a with statement is sql syntax similar in effect to a sub query.

With statements allow for the ability to break down a query into smaller efficient steps and ultimately are used to produce a query result.

Since the goal of with statements is to produce a query result, with statements can exist inside views.